# Span a ASP:TextBox

Tags: asp.net

I have a table with two rows with four columns.  I have text in the first column in the first row and a textbox in the second column, then text and then a textbox.  In the next row I have text in the first column and a textbox in the second, but I want to span the textbox to fill the other two columns so everything lines up correctly.  Can I do this in a single table or do I need to create a table so that the columns can be different sizes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use column span (colspan) attribute of html `<table/>`.

For instance:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">Text</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
    <td>Text1</td>
    <td>Text2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to do this programmatically, you can set the ColumnSpan property of each TableCell within an ASP.NET Table control.  Then use the Width or Columns property of the TextBox you put into that cell to make it as wide as you like.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.tablecell.columnspan%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.textbox_members%28v=vs.80%29.aspx